# call function unintentionally excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following sub that has worked for months:

```
Sub copy_over_csv_files()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wbName As String:                  wbName = ThisWorkbook.Name
    Dim totalSheets As Integer:

    Dim filePath As String '  used to hold file path for finding the needed csv file

    Dim fileName As String
    Dim fileNameArray() As Variant
    ReDim fileNameArray(9)

    fileNameArray = Array("x.csv", _
    "y.csv", "z.csv", _
    "n.csv", "q.csv", _
    "r.csv", "s.csv", _
    "a.csv", "b.csv", "c.csv")

    Dim n As Integer '  counter for file names array loop

    For n = 0 To 9

       totalSheets = Workbooks(wbName).Sheets.Count


        filePath = "Macintosh HD:Users:file1:file2:file3:" & fileNameArray(n)
        ChDir "Macintosh HD:Users:file1:file2:file3:"

        Workbooks.Open fileName:=filePath ' file path to needed file

        Sheets(fileNameArray(n)).Select

        Sheets(fileNameArray(n)).Copy After:=Workbooks(wbName).Sheets(totalSheets)

        Windows(fileNameArray(n)).Activate

        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Next n

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Then I wrote the following function:

```
Function GetAgentEmailWorksheet(AgentObjectId As String)
    Dim specific_agent As clsAgent
    Set specific_agent = New clsAgent

    specific_agent.AgentSheetName = "agentsFullOutput.csv"

    Dim id_array() As Variant
    id_array = specific_agent.AgentIDArray

    Dim email_array() As Variant
    email_array = specific_agent.AgentEmailArray

    GetAgentEmailWorksheet = vlook_using_array(AgentObjectId, id_array, email_array)

End Function
```

For some reason, the following line in the first sub: `Sheets(fileNameArray(n)).Copy After:=Workbooks(wbName).Sheets(totalSheets)`
 opens the function.

I don't know why and I don't know how to make it stop.

Comment: You will have to give us enough information to reproduce the problem, else we can't help. See this for guidance: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Right now I can only take a random guess: do you have a `Workbook_NewSheet` event?

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of info, but I didn't want to post the whole class...etc.  seems like too much code.  I don't know what `Workbook_NewSheet` is, but I you mean this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821246.aspx then, no. I don't.  I was hoping someone could explain how a function could get called without it being called directly in the code.

Comment: It seems really strange and really improbable as a behavior. I would say: 1) check all your events, see where the function is called and try to understand why; 2) debug the code and tell us what happens between when you call the line and when you get into the function (is it direct? Or you pass through other code?); 3) Make sure you don't have a shadow code (sometimes, if you don't compile, it might be that on the VBE you see something but the compiled code, on that part, contains something else.

Comment: @dwstein: I don't want you to post the whole class. On the contrary. Did you read the link I gave you? It's about creating the *minimal* example necessary to reproduce the problem i.e. with as few lines of code as possible. That way it's nice and isolated and easier to diagnose. Please take a minute and read it — if you expect us to take some time and help you.